# Javascript solution to find each substring between a prefix and suffix

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string in below format ,

> `Hello this #result1# is a sample #result2# string with a lot of # and  #result3# i need to find all the values between #`

I need javascript or nodejs based solution which can return `['result1' , 'result2' , 'result3']` only.

Rules :

1. There is no space between expected results
2. There is no `#` between expected results.
3. It should exclude results like `['result1# is a sample #result2# string with a lot of ' , 'result1# is a sample ']`

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a very simple task and should be quite easy to find with a minimum of effort searching SO, or the web in general.

Answer (score 1):

Below code snippet should work:

```js
let str = "Hello this #result1# is a sample #result2# string with a lot of # and  #result3# i need to find all the values between #";
let identifier = '#';

function getSubstrings(str, identifier) {
    let results = [];
    let splittedItems = str.split(identifier);
    splittedItems.forEach(
        function(item) {
            if (item.length > 1 && item.indexOf(' ') === -1) {
                results.push(item);
            }
        }
    );
    return results;
}
document.write(getSubstrings(str, identifier));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = 'Hello this #result1# is a sample #result2# string with a lot of # and  #result3# i need to find all the values between #';
console.log(str.match(/#[^#\s]+#/g));
```

**Explanation:**

```
/        : regex delimiter
 #       : # character
 [^#\s]+ : 1 or more character that is NOT # or space
 #       : # character
/g       : regex delimiter and global flag
```

Comment: Upvoted because you provided an explanation of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
/#(.*?)#
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/hPsMVo/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your question could have many special cases and without details about what you tried and how it failed, it is difficult to give a definitive answer.
You could try starting with the following:

```
var input = 'Hello this #result1# is a sample #result2# string with a lot of # and  #result3# i need to find all the values between #';
output = input.match(/#[A-Za-z0-9]+#/g);
console.log(output); //["#result1#", "#result2#", "#result3#"]
```

`[A-Za-z0-9]` matches any uppercase letter (`A-Z`), lowercase letter (`a-z`) and number (`0-9`)

`+` means the preceding pattern should be present at least one time

`g` means global, so matches all the occurences of the pattern in the string

It should get you going.